# How can I call an anonymous function with arguments in Nashorn?

Tags: java, nashorn

I am trying to execute a for each function in Javascript, using Nashorn, which I've defined in Java.

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine eng = mgr.getEngineByExtension("js");
eng.put("script", new ScriptAPI());
try {
    eng.eval("script.each([1,2,3], function(i){ print('i = ' + i); });");
} catch(ScriptException e)
{ e.printStackTrace(); }
```

As you can see, my script is calling `script.each`, wherein `script` has been defined as an instance of the `ScriptAPI`, which looks as follows:

```
public class ScriptAPI {
    public void each(Object[] arr, Runnable function) {
        for(Object o : arr) function.run();
    }
}
```

However, you might have noticed that I'm not passing the `Object o` to the function; this is because `function.run` doesn't take any arguments - So how can I pass arguments to this anonymous function?

Comment: For those trying to figure out this works: **JS:** test(function(a) { print(a); }); **Java:** public void test(Consumer<Object> test) { test.accept("yo"); } *This prints "yo".*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Runnable.run` doesn't, of course, accept any arguments. Just use [`Consumer<Object>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html):

```
public void each(Object[] arr, Consumer<Object> function) {
    for(Object o : arr) function.accept(o);
}
```

(Or define your own functional interface and use that.)